# Refactoring repeated ternary statements?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, ternary-operator

I'm reviewing PR's, and the author has a situation where they are using repeated ternaries, thus -

```js
const foo = isConditionTrue ? 'foo' : '';
const bar = isConditionTrue ? 'bar' : '';
const baz = isConditionTrue ? 'baz' : '';
```

This seems repetitive but a better method doesn't immediately spring to mind. I've thought about assigning to an empty string and reassigning in an `if` block, but I don't feel that's any cleaner.

Any suggestions helpful, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use array destructoring..

```js
const isConditionTrue = true;
const [foo,bar,baz] = isConditionTrue ? 
    ["foo", "bar","baz"] : ["","",""];
    
console.log(foo, bar, baz);
```

Comment: If longer, `Array(3).fill("")` might be better. And one should note that this is ES6

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, `Array.fill`, if you have more conditions would work nicely here too.  ES6, I tend not to mention this now, I personally think were at a stage now were if you require ES5, the OP should mention it.  We need to put ES5 were it belongs, in the History books. :)  Also the OP was using `const` so he should be Ok with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could curry the problem and take a predefined function where you just insert the value for a true condition.

```
const setCondition = (condition, default) => value => condition ? value : default;

const checkCondition = setCondition(isConditionTrue, '');

const foo = checkCondition('foo');
const bar = checkCondition('bar');
const baz = checkCondition('baz');
```